# Field parameter in Modelbuilder - empty?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, fields-attributes, parameters

I have built a model, as input parameter I have a 2 parameters: a Feature Layer and a Field
But when I run the model, the Field-Parameter has no values to select.
How can I tell the model builder, that I want the Fields from the selected Feature Layer as values in the Field parameter?

Comment: I would look into tool validation. I think you can use this with tools authored using ModelBuilder and not just Python script tools but I am happy to be corrected.  Actually I think it is an Obtained from option when you are setting Parameters on the Model Properties but tool validation is useful to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to derive a field from a layer, this can only be done in a script tool, it is discussed [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000n000000). You will need to convert the logic of the model into python code.